# Find specific tet and print it to same column - awk,sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed, match

I have .tsv INPUT with two column.

```
cosmic=1559412:35423    dbsnp=rs80358762
cosmic=23930
dbsnp=rs80359637:rs80358961
cosmic=172579:172578    dbsnp=rs80358435
cosmic=219056    dbsnp=rs80359350:rs80359351:rs80359352:rs80359353
```

And I want one column. OUTPUT:

```
dbsnp=rs80358762
N/A
dbsnp=rs80359637:rs80358961
dbsnp=rs80358435 
dbsnp=rs80359350:rs80359351:rs80359352:rs80359353
```

I tried

```
awk a=/dbsnp/'{print $a }' dbsnp.tsv
```

but it is bad idea. Or use MATCH. 
Could you help me please..

Comment: Or this one awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i=="dbsnp"){print $i} } }' dbsnp.tsv but it is not working

Comment: did you want `N/A` to be printed.

Comment: @FilipZembol - you are WAY off on awk syntax. Get the book `Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition` by Arnold Robbins and read at least the opening chapters of that to get an idea on awk syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with awk

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/dbsnp/)print $i}!/dbsnp/{print "N/A"}' dbsnp.tsv
```

You almost had it in your comment but you matched `dbsnp` with `$i=="dbsnp"` but the fields contain other things. Using `$i~/dbsnp/` matches if the field contains `dbsnp`

Comment: Should be `awk -F'\t' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/dbsnp=/){print $i;next}; print "N/A"}' dbsnp.tsv`

Comment: @ooga why should it ?

Comment: @Jidder - to avoid redundantly specifying the same RE twice (the 2nd the negation of the first) and to avoid problems when the tab-separated fields contain blank chars and to avoid problems when the letters `dbsnp` appear mid-line instead of at the start of a field and followed by `=`. @ooga also needs `/dbsnp=/` to have a start-of-string anchor `/^dbsnp=/`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're also open to `sed` solutions, you might be able to simply remove the "cosmic" column:

```
sed 's/cosmic=[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*//' input.tsv
```

This simply substitutes the offending column into nonexistence.

If you really want the `N/A` to be output when nothing is found, you could do this:

```
sed -ne 's/cosmic=[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*//;s:^$:N/A:;p' input.tsv
```

This does the same substitution as before, but replaces blank lines with "N/A".

**Proviso:** Per ams' accurate observation, `[:space:]` is not the same as a tab (your delimiter).  For proper handling of your input (where "cosmic" might include spaces), replace `[:space:]` with a literal tab.

---

And since you're also open to a `bash` solution, here's how you can achieve this without any external tools:

```
shopt -s extglob;
while read line; do
  echo "${line/cosmic=+([^$'\t'])?([$'\t'])/}";
done < input.tsv
```

Again, to replace the blank line with `N/A`, a little more logic is required:

```
shopt -s extglob;
while read line; do
  line="${line/cosmic=+([^$'\t'])?([$'\t'])/}";
  test -z "$line" && echo "N/A" || echo "$line";
done < input.tsv
```

The trailing semicolons are of course redundant; I've left them in place here so that you can easily copy-and-paste these into one-liners if you wish.

Note that setting `extglob` is required if you want the `+(...)` pattern expressions, which you'd need for this complexity of text parsing.

Comment: `[:space:]` is not the same as `\t`, which would be more appropriate for TSV.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, but `\t` doesn't work in any version of `sed` I've seen except GNU's.  Portability++.  If you don't want to use `[:space:]`, you can replace it with a literal tab, but that's harder to show in `<code>`. Updated the answer to point this out.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{print ($NF~/^dbsnp=/ ? $NF : "N/A")}' file
dbsnp=rs80358762
N/A
dbsnp=rs80359637:rs80358961
dbsnp=rs80358435
dbsnp=rs80359350:rs80359351:rs80359352:rs80359353
```

Answer (score 1):

This ought to work:

```
awk -F '\t' 'NF > 1 {print $2; next} /^dbsnp=/ {print $1; next} /.*/ {print "N/A"}' dbsnp.tsv
```

This says:

1. If there are more than one field, use the second, and move the next line.
2. Otherwise, if the first (and only) field starts with `dbnsp=` then print it, and move to the next line.
3. Otherwise, just print "N/A". (`/.*/` matches everything.)

The `next` is important because that what adds the "otherwise" to the following rules.

Comment: I don't think that will work (won't it print `N/A` for the third line of the input?). And it would normally be written `awk -F'\t' 'NF > 1 {print $2; next} {print "N/A"}' dbsnp.tsv`

Comment: That quite clearly wont work. It will print `N/A` for every single line

Comment: I tried this code and it is working, but I do not understand of /.*/

Comment: @Jidder that's what `next` is for.

Comment: I have 8 space sized tabs, so it didn't match any, surely using the default separator would not be a problem ?

Comment: @Jidder that depends if other whitespace can occur in any column.

Comment: @FilipZembol said "tsv", so the default separator is clearly wrong. Of course, any regexp solution will fail if there are tabs within quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't that *simple* `sed` command do the trick?

```
sh$ sed -n -e 's/^.*dbsnp=/dbsnp=/p' -e '/^dbsnp=/!c N/A' < dbsnp.tsv
dbsnp=rs80358762
N/A
dbsnp=rs80359637:rs80358961
dbsnp=rs80358435
dbsnp=rs80359350:rs80359351:rs80359352:rs80359353
```

I think this could easily be adapted to the various subtleties of your data file.

Answer (score 1):

Command:

```
sed -r 's/.*(dbsnp=.*)/\1/;TM;p;d;:M;c\N/A' dbsnp.tsv
```

Output:

```
dbsnp=rs80358762
N/A
dbsnp=rs80359637:rs80358961
dbsnp=rs80358435
dbsnp=rs80359350:rs80359351:rs80359352:rs80359353
```